# how to set magit commit author?

Tags: git

i am using magit to do a git push, it fail with below error message:
remote: ERROR:  committer email address XXXX
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.

so i have to do this commit thru Git, why magit does not work?

Comment: If you run the command `git config -l --global` in the command line does `user.email` match your user account? If it doesn't you can update it using `git config -e --global`.

Comment: git config -l --global run result is different with magit , the git config is the right email , but the question is , how can i change the magit wrong email?

Comment: From the [magit user manual](http://magit.github.com/magit/magit.html): Typing C-c C-t will toggle the option to specify the name and email address for the commit's author. The default is determined by the user.name and user.email git configuration settings.

Comment: and another question is that how to change the committer name and email in magit？i　did not find any clue in the Manaul, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"add a HOME enviroment varibales and specify the dir the same with the .gitconfig dir" sovleve this problem.

it is because the magit can not find the .gitconfig file in the HOME dir.

Comment: Setting HOME in Windows has solved a few Emacs problems for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the above (or below) answer by @Björn Lindqvist with CAUTION. Do it ONLY if you know what you are going or it might ruin your environmental variables. Just a word of caution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.emacs` to get it to work:

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (setenv "HOME" (concat (getenv "HOMEDRIVE") (getenv "HOMEPATH"))))
```

Much later... **Don't use this code!** It will confuse Emacs and make it unable to locate the correct `~/.emacs` file. The only right way is to set the `HOME` environment variable for the user.